# Vs code. Synchronization problems

Tags: visual-studio-code, github

Vs code. Synchronization problems. 2 computers were synchronized. A crash has occurred.

Now it shows that 5 computers were synchronized, although there were only 2 of them. The main problem is that extensions are not synchronized

Question 1: How can I make a complete synchronization collection with clearing all settings, with clearing data in the cloud and resetting the number of computers that were synchronized?

Question 2: through which cloud account is it better to do synchronization? Microsoft or GitHub

I have restarted synchronization many times on one computer, then on another. No effect